# grails : org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Anyone familiar with the following error? 
I am using hibernate 4+with Grails 2.4.4

This is the entire error log:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
...........
|Compiling 1 source files
.........................
|Running Grails application
Error |
2015-03-19 16:54:11,496 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MappingException: Association references unmapped class: java.util.Set
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

- one of my domain classes contained a capital letter where it shouldn't( 'Exploits' instead of 'exploits' ).

The Solution:

old code:

```
package core

class Scenario {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [ Exploit ]

    static hasMany = [ Exploits : Exploit ]

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false , maxSize: 32
    }
}
```

new code :

```
package core

class Scenario {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [ Exploit ]

    static hasMany = [ exploits : Exploit ]

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false , maxSize: 32
    }
}
```

it works!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you are using  a collection like hasMany in an embedded object.

Composite elements may not hold nested collections.

"Composite Elements" are the same as @Embeddable objects. So, it is not possible for a collection of @Embeddable objects to hold collections. They must be promoted to @Entity objects.

refer [this link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2328033#p2328033)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading my project from Grails 2.3.11 to 2.5.4. It turned out that it was the spring-security generated classes User, Role and UserRole that had to be updated. They had getters and setters that were obsolete and that were now interpreted as bean attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar exception but naming was correct.

The problem was was two data sources using - for read and write replicas.

Fix for the issue was adding the following:

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'ALL'
}
```